# Javascript videoplayer attack vectors

Tags: javascript, web-service, attack-vector

My team is building a Javascript-based video player for our own platform, instead of relying on other already available options like `video.js`.

I'm wondering which attack vectors should I take into consideration, bearing in mind that we are not hosting any website, we just deploy the Javascript code to our customers and they are the ones who host the code in their website.

In other words, the workflow is more or less like: a client connect to our customer's site for playing a video, our customer downloads from our server the latest version of the player, our customer display the video in his site.

[image]

So we don't have any input, so I guess XSS wouldn't be possible (I may be wrong though). What other attacks, should I take into consideration?

Comment: How does the client indicate what video they want to watch? That seems like an input to me!

Comment: @Matthew the client indicates the video to the website. **The website is our customer**, they just download the video player from us. We don't have any video feed, that's the website business not ours.

Comment: In other words, there are three different parties: `Client` is customer of `Website` and `Website` is customer of `Video player server` (us).

Comment: whoever is voting for closing, show yourself and say why you think it should be closed.

Comment: @yzT you might try to narrow your question down a bit by explicitly stating that it is only about the security of the JavaScript code itself, not about the rest of the infrastructure (security of video player server, etc). Personally, I don't think that your question is too broad, but that might convince others to reopen your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DOM-based XSS is something you want to look out for.

You might have code in your video player that reads out part of the URL - for example to get the id of the currently playing video or some video settings such as width - and inserts it into the DOM, leading to XSS.

Other than that, there isn't much that you can do wrong. Your `Video player server` only serves a static file, so if the server software itself is up-to-date, there shouldn't be any danger to it. Your script will also not be able to do any damage to `Website`, as that server should of course validate any user input it gets.

Comment: there is no `id` as I told to Matthew there is no video in our side. However, I'm not sure about where is the resolution being validated. I think the website downloads the raw code and it's at its side where the resolution in changed. Will need to look for it.

Comment: @yzT `id` was just an example, there are many things that you may read out of the URL and insert into the DOM, resulting in DOM based XSS (which is really the main - and, if I understand your question correctly, only - security issue you need to worry about regarding the implementation of the js script [server and network security would of course be another thing to worry about, but that's always the case]).

Answer (score 1):

I don't have enough reputation to comment on Tim's post with which I agree, so I'll just post here but this is not a full answer.

In addition to what Tim stated, make sure that the js transfer is made over `https` to prevent classic man-in-the-middle attacks. Since you are partially playing the role of a `CDN`, you don't want the integrity of your deliverable at risk.

In a possibly unlikely but realistic scenario someone could alter your `javascript` in a `MITM` attack to include attack vectors / payloads in the code.

Hopefully this was planned, but since you didn't mention it, better check twice than none :)

Comment: well, that's basic nowadays. I'm interested in vulnerabilities in the code itself. Anyway, +1 for trying to help, so soon you can comment :)